# SQL Server error "Invalid Column Name" when trying to select from table mapping

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic

```
SELECT 
    (CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), tb.Timestamp, 108)) AS MeasuredDateTime,
    CAST(tb.Mould_protection_force_actual_value * 200 AS  NUMERIC(18, 2))
FROM 
    (SELECT Table_name 
     FROM PIM01_Group_Mapping 
     WHERE Param_code = 'IM0001') AS tb
WHERE  
    Tb.Timestamp > DATEADD(MINUTE, -1, GETDATE()) 
    AND tb.Timestamp < CONVERT(DATETIME, GetDate() - 0)
ORDER BY 
    MeasuredDateTime
```

I am trying to get the table name using a select statement in `FROM CLAUSE` in which I wanted to fetch few column values.

Getting error

> INVALID COLUMN

My idea is I want the Table name and column names to be dynamically loaded from a mapping table when I execute the above procedure.

Any ideas?

Comment: @randy Does SSMS not tell you the name of the column that is supposedly Invalid??

Comment: SQL Server doesn't make it easy to mix *data* and *metadata* in a single query. You were expecting it to treat a *string*, selected from a table, as a *name*. These are not the same things. In general, if you're trying to parameterise table or column names (and thus mix metadata and data), it's usually an indication that your data modelling has gone wrong and some of your data *has been modelled as metatdata instead*. I.e. rather than it being directly queryable against, it's embedded in table or column names.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write `DYNAMIC QUERY`.

Try this:

**Solution 1:**

```
DECLARE @Query VARCHAR(2000),@TableName VARCHAR(500)

SELECT @TableName = Table_name FROM PIM01_Group_Mapping WHERE Param_code = 'IM0001'

SET @Query='
SELECT (CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),tb.Timestamp,108)) as MeasuredDateTime,
    CAST(tb.Mould_protection_force_actual_value * 200 AS  NUMERIC(18,2))
FROM '+@TableName+' AS tb
WHERE  Tb.Timestamp > DATEADD(MINUTE,-1,GETDATE()) AND tb.Timestamp < CONVERT(DATETIME,GetDate()-0)
ORDER BY MeasuredDateTime'

EXEC (@Query)
```

**Solution 2:**

Or you directly Call the table name in the Query.

```
DECLARE @Query VARCHAR(2000)

SET @Query='
SELECT (CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),tb.Timestamp,108)) as MeasuredDateTime,
    CAST(tb.Mould_protection_force_actual_value * 200 AS  NUMERIC(18,2))
FROM '+(SELECT Table_name FROM PIM01_Group_Mapping WHERE Param_code = 'IM0001')+' AS tb
WHERE  Tb.Timestamp > DATEADD(MINUTE,-1,GETDATE()) AND tb.Timestamp < CONVERT(DATETIME,GetDate()-0)
ORDER BY MeasuredDateTime'

EXEC (@Query)
```

If you want to view the Query, use `Print` to get the Execution Query.

```
PRINT (@Query)
```

Comment: Timestamp , Mould_protection etc are not from the table "PIM01_Group_Mapping" . I have  table names as colums in PIM01_Group_Mapping table and i went to get the table name from that before getting the values Timestamp,Mould_protection_force_actual_value

Comment: @Harry all the columns are throwing invalid column error eg:Timestamp,Mould_protection_force_actual_value

Comment: @Randy, Are you try my updated answer? Is there any issues?